# Android kotlin google play billing onPurchasesUpdated overrides nothing or is never used

Tags: java, android, kotlin, billing

I'm following this docs to implement google pay:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

After running this function and purchage a product:

```
fun buy() {

    val skuList = listOf("vip_small")

    if (billingClient.isReady) {
        val params = SkuDetailsParams
                .newBuilder()
                .setSkusList(skuList)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                .build()
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { responseCode, skuDetailsList ->

            if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {

                Log.d("lets", "querySkuDetailsAsync, responseCode: $responseCode")


                val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSku("vip_small")
                        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP) // SkuType.SUB for subscription
                        .build()

                val responseCodee = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams)

                Log.d("lets", "launchBillingFlow responseCode: $responseCodee")

            } else {
                Log.d("lets", "Can't querySkuDetailsAsync, responseCode: $responseCode")
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("lets", "Billing Client not ready")
    }
}
```

which works fine I want to know if the purchage has been made so I add this code from the cods:

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(@BillingResponse responseCode: Int, purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
    if (responseCode == BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (purchase in purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase)
        }
    } else if (responseCode == BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
    } else {
        // Handle any other error codes.
    }
}
```

But I get the error `'onPurchasesUpdated' overrides nothing`

So I remove `override` and get this "error"

```
Function "onPurchasesUpdated" is never used
```

What the hell?? How to call this damn function after the purchage has been made?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution.

You need to make the activity/fragment use the `PurchasesUpdatedListener` like:

```
class VIP : AppCompatActivity(), PurchasesUpdatedListener {

}
```

Then override will work